# How to split a Mercurial chain into independent changes merging at the tip

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I started working on a commit, let's call it `C`

`master - C (tip)`

However, after a series of splits, I ended up with something like

`master - A - B - C (tip)`

As it turns out, `A` and `B` are independent of each other but `C` depends on both. Is there a way to split this chain in such a way that I can work on `A` and `B` independently:

```
master - A - merge - C (tip)
      \     /
        - B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as long as you haven't pushed your changes yet. If you've pushed and other people have replicated the original series of `A-B-C` changesets you can't easily undo that.

There are in fact several ways to do this... this is what I think is the most straightforward.

STEP 1:

`hg up master`

`hg revert -r B`

`hg commit`  (consider this `B2`)

So now `B2` looks like the original B but follows `master` instead of `A`. The original `B` still exists for now:

```
master - A - B - C
       \
         B2
```

STEP 2:

`hg merge -r A`

`hg revert -r C`

`hg commit` (consider this `C2`)

And now you have:

```
master - A  - B - C
       \    \
         B2 - C2
```

STEP 3:

Finally clean up your original unwanted `B` & `C`:

`hg strip B`

Note that strip is technically an extension so you might have to enable it in your `hgrc`.

Comment - in step 1 you could use also `graft` instead of `revert` to replicate `B` to `B2`. I tend to use `revert` because it is more versatile but it does require an explicit `commit` that `graft` would avoid.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up doing something similar but slightly different, shortly after I asked the question:

`hg up master`
`hg graft B`
`hg merge A`
`hg rebase -s C -d mergedAB'`
`hg rebase -s B -d master`
`hg merge A`
`hg rebase -s C -d mergedAB`
`hg strip mergedAB'`
`hg strip B'`

This allowed me to keep the treat the graft as temporary and keep the original A and B commits. Your approach with `hg revert` instead of `hg graft` is more versatile though. I'll try to modify your approach while keeping the original branches intact.

Comment: @user34812 that sounds reasonable. One reason I suggested the method in this answer is that it totally preserves your original commit series until you are 100% ready to remove it. You could totally back out the changes if needed without breaking anything original.